# Почему при любом способе подключения OpenCV выдается ошибка `undefined reference to ...`?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, mingw

Операционная система - `Windows 10`

Я пробовал собирать OpenCV самостоятельно, но при любом использовании API OpenCV, даже при простом объявлении `cv::Mat mat;` код не компилируется. Такая же ошибка возникает и при использовании уже [собранной версии OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/download/4.5.5/).

Проект компилируется при помощи `MinGW`, собирается при помощи `CMake`.

Конфиг `CMake`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(ImagePixelizer VERSION 0.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_subdirectory(lib/tinyfd)

add_executable(ImagePixelizer src/main.cpp src/SelectFileDialog/FileDialog.cpp)

target_include_directories(ImagePixelizer PRIVATE
        lib/SFML/include/
        lib/OpenCV/include
        lib/tinyfd/include)

target_link_libraries(
        ImagePixelizer
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics.a
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/SFML/lib/libsfml-window.a
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/SFML/lib/libsfml-system.a
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/OpenCV/lib/opencv_world455.lib
        TinyFileDialogs)
```

Файлы библиотеки:

[image: Структура файлов подключённой библиотеки]

Папку include показывать не стал, так как там всё как надо.

Также добавил в переменную среды Path путь к `.dll` библиотеки.

Comment: Для начала следует раздобыть версию opecv собранную используемой версией компилятора. `.lib` - это расширение статических библиотек или библиотек импорта visual c++

Comment: @user7860670, Если это действительно поможет, то я и сам соберу, пожалуй :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что библиотека, скомпилированная одним компилятором, не будет прочтена другим компилятором.

[Данная версия OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/download/4.5.5/opencv-4.5.5-vc14_vc15.exe) была скомпилирована компилятором Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 (файлы библиотеки находятся в папке vc15) и не могла быть прочитана моим MinGW. А когда я компилировал библиотеку собственноручно, то также совершал данную ошибку, генерируя проект для Visual Studio 2022.

### Сборка OpenCV компилятором MinGW.

Чтобы скомпилировать исходный код для MinGW я выполнил такой порядок действий:

1. Добавил путь к `MinGW` в переменную среды `Path`, чтобы его мог использовать CMake и я из командной строки.
2. [Скачал исходный код библиотеки.](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/refs/tags/4.5.5.zip) (Версия 4.5.5)
3. Сконфигурировал и сгенерировал проект для компилятора из `MinGW`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Открыл командную строку в папке, куда `СMake` кладёт бинарники (`Where to build the binares`) и выполнил команду `mingw32-make install`, после чего пошёл достаточно долгий процесс компиляции библиотеки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5. Далее, согласно инструкции из командной строки после завершения компиляции, я открыл `(папку с бинарниками из пункта 4)/install`. Там находятся динамические и статические библиотеки (библиотеки импорта, как я понял) в соответствующих папках. Эти файлы переносим в проект. Файлы заголовков лежат в `/install/include`.
6. После чего уже, соответственно, можно линковаться со всеми необходимыми вам статическими библиотеками, и, либо положить `.dll`-ки в папку с исполняемым файлом, либо добавить в `Path`.

```
target_link_libraries(
        Target
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs455.dll.a
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_imgproc455.dll.a
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_core455.dll.a
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_highgui455.dll.a
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_gapi455.dll.a
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_video455.dll.a
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_videoio455.dll.a
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/OpenCV/lib/libopencv_photo455.dll.a)
```

После проделанных махинаций проект успешно запускается без каких-либо ошибок.

За подсказку спасибо [@user7860670](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/272035/user7860670).